# Can not set custom collection name for mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read the manual https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection and I think I did the necessary to specify my custom collection name  but it doesn't work:

Here is my model `User.js`:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  number: {
    type: Number
  }

}, { collection: 'userList' });

export default  (mongoose.models?.User || mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'userList', false));
```

In one of my pages I create a new record in the following way:

```
import User from "../models/User";

....
await dbConnect();
const randStr = String(Math.random() * 1000 )
let newUser = new User
newUser.name =  'My name is ' + randStr 
newUser.email =  'supercool@' + randStr 
newUser.number = 155;
await newUser.save();
console.log(newUser)
```

I observe two things that are wrong:

1. Instead of creating `userList` collection I get `users` collection created.
2. In  my schema I've defined `number` property it is not being saved upon new record created.

Im not sure if it is expected behavior but I deliberately not defined email field in my schema, but when I add such property into the model I get it saved.

Here is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Should be `mongoose.model('userList', userSchema));` See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling, the first param should be collection name. Since you are giving 'User', its taking 'users' (lowercased plural form), which is default for moongoose

Comment: I found the problem.
When I replace `export default  (mongoose.models?.User || mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'userList', false));` with `export default  mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'userList', false));` it wokrs. The changes in schema are accepted. For some reason the first condition is true even after server restart (very strange). Then I have to return to the first version because I get different errors on insert/update. Pretty ugly.